# Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found, Message: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found,Filename: controllers/Welcome.php Line Number: 62

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

Hi I am getting PHPExcel_IOFactory not found error for below-mentioned line

```
$objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
```

//controller

```
function ExcelDataAdd() 
{  
     $configUpload['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
     $configUpload['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx|csv';
     $configUpload['max_size'] = '5000';
     $this->load->library('upload', $configUpload);
     $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');  
     $upload_data = $this->upload->data();  
     $file_name = $upload_data['file_name']; 
     $extension=$upload_data['file_ext'];

      $objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
      $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
      $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load('./uploads/'.$file_name);     
      $totalrows=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();   
      $objWorksheet=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);      
      for($i=2;$i<=$totalrows;$i++)
      {
          $FirstName= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();     
          $LastName= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue(); 

          $this->Excel_export_model->Add_stud($data_stud);     
      }
      unlink('./uploads/'.$file_name);                     
      redirect("Welcome");
    }
```

please tell me where am I going wrong

Comment: Have you included `PHPExcel` files? AFAIR there's `Autoload.php` or something similar.

Comment: yes, I have included all the files

Comment: are you inside a namespace? if so, put `use PHPExcel_IOFactory` under the namespace declaration

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: @RajeshwariNesargi can you try this `$this->load->library('PHPExcel');` then `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` if you get error then share that

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I haven't loaded the model in function. Below mentioned function is working correctly

```
function ExcelDataAdd() 
{  
     $configUpload['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
     $configUpload['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx|csv';
     $configUpload['max_size'] = '5000';
     $this->load->library('upload', $configUpload);
     $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');  
     $upload_data = $this->upload->data();  
     $file_name = $upload_data['file_name']; 
     $extension=$upload_data['file_ext'];

      $objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
      $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
      $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load('./uploads/'.$file_name);     
      $totalrows=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();   
      $objWorksheet=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);      
      for($i=2;$i<=$totalrows;$i++)
      {
          $FirstName= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();     
          $LastName= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue(); 
          $data_stud=array('optra_id'=>$optra_id, 'student_fname'=>$student_fname);print_r($data_stud);
              $this->load->model("Excel_export_model");
          $this->Excel_export_model->Add_stud($data_stud);     
      }
      unlink('./uploads/'.$file_name);                     
      redirect("Welcome");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$this->load->library('PHPExcel');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$sheet1 = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->toArray(null,true,true,true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($sheet1);die;
```

where `file` is the name of the file tag like `<input type="file" name="file">`

Please Download PHPExcel from this link and paste into `application/library/` folder

[https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Classes]